# C++11 segfault on reference to unordered_map in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, emplace

When i run the following code I get a segfault on the 'find()' call.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

struct item {
    std::unordered_map<int,int> map;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   std::vector<item> stack;
   stack.emplace_back();
   std::unordered_map<int,int>& topmap=stack.back().map;
   stack.emplace_back();
   auto ind=topmap.find(5);
   if(ind!=topmap.end()) {
      printf("Found element five in second to top item\n");
   }
}
```

(compiled with -std=c++11)

However, if the second emplace_back() call is removed, there is no segfault.

Why is this? Am I using reference variables wrong?  Does adding another element to the stack invalidate topmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the second call to `emplace_back` causes a re-allocation, invalidating `topmap`. You can easily check this by looking at `stack.capacity()`. If that changes between calls, there has been a re-allocation.

Comment: Woops, this is obviously the explanation. I should use std::list instead if I want my references to remain valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), you will see the text

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated."

Adding new items to the end of a vector typically reallocates the data inside the vector and causes this behavior. More specifically, since `map` is an ordinary instance inside the structure, it will too be reallocated.

Answer (score 1):

> Does adding another element to the stack invalidate topmap?

Not mandatory, but it can. It depends if reallocation happened when `std::vector::emplace_back()` is called.
[std::vector::emplace_back documentation:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
>   references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.